# Issue with \loop to create contents of tabular row

Tags: tables, macros, conditionals, loops

I want to create a table where items in columns are alphabetic `A,B,C,......,M`, and I would like insert them with a loop, here an example

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{countA}

\def\myline{}
\loop\ifnum\thecountA<12
  \stepcounter{countA}
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\myline\expandafter{%
    \myline
    \Alph{countA} &  
  }%
\repeat

\begin{document}

\centering 

\begin{tabular}{|*{13}{c|}}
\hline
A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & G & K & L & M \\  
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|*{13}{c|}}
\hline
\myline M\\  
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The result is a tabular where all cells contain the same letter L, how can I fix `myline` macro  to obtain same as the first table, or if there another method to create such loop in tabular

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `\myline` is not expanded. Using `\edef` instead of `\def` and removing al the `expandafter`s solves this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{countA}

\def\myline{}
\loop\ifnum\thecountA<12
  \stepcounter{countA}
  \edef\myline{%
    \myline
    \Alph{countA} &  
  }%
\repeat

\begin{document}

\centering 

\begin{tabular}{|*{13}{c|}}
\hline
A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & G & K & L & M \\  
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|*{13}{c|}}
\hline
\myline M\\  
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example without using `\loop...\repeat` (recursive):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{countA}
\def\myline{%
    \stepcounter{countA}\Alph{countA}&%
    \ifnum\thecountA<12%
    \myline
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
\centering 

\begin{tabular}{|*{13}{c|}}
\hline
A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & G & K & L & M \\  
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|*{13}{c|}}
\hline
\myline M\\  
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: This needs the counter `countA` to be set to `0` each time the macro is called, because the loop is executed each time `\myline` is called instead of saving the results of the loop into `\myline`. One might solve this by inserting a `\else\setcounter{countA}{0}`, but the loop is still executed everytime.

EDIT2: To allow stuff similar to egreg's "more generic approach" but making it even more generic:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{countA}
\newcommand{\myline}[2][0]{%
    \ifnum#1>0\setcounter{countA}{#1}\fi%
    \stepcounter{countA}\Alph{countA}&%
    \ifnum\numexpr#2-1>\value{countA}%
    \myline{#2}%
    \else%
    \stepcounter{countA}\Alph{countA}%
    \setcounter{countA}{0}%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}
\centering 

\begin{tabular}{|*{13}{c|}}
\hline
A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & G & K & L & M \\  
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|*{13}{c|}}
\hline
\myline{13}\\
\hline
\myline[13]{26}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: results]

Answer (score 2):

A more generic approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{countA}
\newcommand{\alphline}[1]{%
  % I want #1 letters
  \setcounter{countA}{1}%
  \def\finalline{A}%
  \loop\ifnum#1>\value{countA}%
    \stepcounter{countA}%
    \xappto\finalline{& \Alph{countA}}%
  \repeat
  \finalline
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*{13}{c|}}
\hline
\alphline{13} \\
% for comparison
A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & G & K & L & M \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Same idea in `expl3` (no counter needed)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\alphline}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { A }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 2 } { 1 } { #1 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { & \int_to_Alph:n { ##1 } }
   }
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*{13}{c|}}
\hline
\alphline{13} \\
% for comparison
A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & G & K & L & M \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```