# Missing number while using loops

Tags: tables, macros, loops

I've been trying to read a number of tex files into a tabular.
I have two sets of files numbered `t_1.tex` ... `t_10.tex` and `a_1.tex` ... `a_10.tex`.

This is the code I have so far:

```
\newcount\ii
\ii=0
\def\myline{}%
\loop
\ifnum\ii<10
\advance\ii by1
\edef\myline{%
\myline
\input{t_\the\ii.tex} & \input{a_\the\ii.tex}\\%
}%
\repeat

\begin{document} 
    \begin{tabular}{l l}
    \myline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I get `Missing number, treated as zero. \repeat`.

There are a couple of similar posts [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361483/issue-with-loop-to-create-contents-of-tabular-row/361492) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50296/problem-with-using-loop-inside-the-tabular-environment). But I can't find the issue in my case.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks for your comment, could you please give an example for my case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's something I picked up from David Carlisle some time ago. (I created files `a_<i>.tex` and `t_<i>.tex` with contents `a<i>` and `t<i>` for i=1,2,3, respectively.) `\myline` is recursively defined, i.e. it "calls" itself until the counter hits the critical value (3 in this example).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{ii}
\setcounter{ii}{0}
\def\singleline{\input{a_\number\value{ii}.tex} &
\input{t_\number\value{ii}.tex}\\}
\def\myline{\stepcounter{ii}%
\ifnum\value{ii}<4
\singleline
\myline
\fi}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tabular}{ll}
 \myline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly!

Comment: @Rashid You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

A simple loop in `expl3`. In the final argument to `\makeloop` you specify the loop template, with `#1` standing for the current loop value.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-a1.tex}
aaa1
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-b1.tex}
bbb1
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-a2.tex}
aaa2
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-b2.tex}
bbb2
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-a3.tex}
aaa3
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-b3.tex}
bbb3
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-a4.tex}
aaa4
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-b4.tex}
bbb4
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\makeloop}{O{1}mm}
 {
  \cs_gset:Nn \__rashid_loop_temp:n { #3 }
  \int_step_function:nnN { #1 } { #2 } \__rashid_loop_temp:n
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\makeloop{4}{\input{\jobname-a#1}\unskip & \input{\jobname-b#1}\unskip \\}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ll}
aaa1 & bbb1 \\
aaa2 & bbb2 \\
aaa3 & bbb3 \\
aaa4 & bbb4 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I used `\jobname` just not to clobber my files.

Note `\unskip` to remove the space inserted by `\input` (the second table is for a check).

The `\makeloop` command has an optional argument for specifying a different starting point: `\makeloop[4]{7}{...}` would make a loop with values 4,5,6,7.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer!